How to numerically find gradient in adjoint method for nonlinear implicit equation
I've been reading this MIT notes pages on the adjoint method: https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.336/adjoint.pdf
In section 3 on nonlinear equations its written that:
If $\mathbf{x}$ satisfied some general, possibly nonlinear equations $\mathbf{f(x,p)}=0$, the process is almost exactly the same. Differentiating the $\mathbf{f}$ equation, we find $\mathbf{f_x x_p + f_p}=0$ and thus $\mathbf{x_p=-f_x^{-1}f_p}$. Hence, we write
$$\frac{dg}{d\mathbf{p}} = g_\mathbf{p}-g_\mathbf{x}(\mathbf{f_x^{-1} f_p}),$$
where $g$ is the scalar objective function.
I'm confused about the practical implementation of something like this. Say for example $x$ satisfies an ODE:
$$\mathbf{f(x,p)} = \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}+x(p) = 0$$
How would one go about finding $\mathbf{f_x}$, $\mathbf{f_p}$? Does this need to be done analytically, or can it be done with a finite difference scheme? We would have have $x$ and $\mathbf{f}$ at $M$ discrete points for a given $\mathbf{p}$ on the forward solve.
